# Virtual Gyroscope in Huawei P Smart 2019 phone?

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, gyroscope

I've got `Huawei P Smart 2019` smartphone. A majority of websites with specs (including official Huawei website) say that there's **no gyroscope** in this model.

- [www.gsmarena.com](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_p_smart_2019-9409.php)
- [www.phonearena.com](https://www.phonearena.com/phones/Huawei-P-Smart-2019_id11057)

But I tested `Huawei P Smart 2019` using Sensor Fusion app. This app detects Gyroscope sensor and shows how it works.

> What's the issue? Why even manufacturer says there's **no gyroscope sensor** in `Huawei P Smart 2019` although a **sensor clearly exists** there?

Maybe it's a `virtual gyroscope`?

```
package org.hitlabnz.sensor_fusion_demo;

public class SensorSelectionActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensor_selection);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        SensorChecker checker = new HardwareChecker((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
        if(!checker.IsGyroscopeAvailable()) {
            displayHardwareMissingWarning();
        }
    }
    private void displayHardwareMissingWarning() {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
        ad.setCancelable(false);   
        ad.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.gyroscope_missing)); 
        ad.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.gyroscope_missing_message));

        ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, getResources().getString(R.string.OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {   
                dialog.dismiss();                      
            }  
        });  
        ad.show();  
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the model id?

Comment: Huawei POT-LX1.

Comment: On the huawei website we ca see : Fingerprint sensor, Proximity sensor, Ambient light sensor, Digital compass, Gravity sensor. Maybe based on all of this sensor he can create emulated gyroscope or something like

Comment: I don't understand how it works but it works. That's what my question about.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/honor-4c/how-to/how-to-enable-virtual-gyroscope-huawei-t3850205 It's look like virtual gyscope exist, so it's probably that haha, but how that's work I can't tell you, but probably that the result of other sensor combinated

Comment: Maybe it's possible by using Compass...

Comment: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/use-google-cardboard-if-your-phone-doesnt-have-gyroscope-0172650/ You can found a ltitle explaination here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little explaination about how it's work : https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/use-google-cardboard-if-your-phone-doesnt-have-gyroscope-0172650/

With the compass and acceleromater sensor on your smartphone, you can make a virtual gyroscope. You need to take the data from compass and acceleromater and make lot of work and sort on it, but you can handle gyroscope functionnality virtualy with that :-)